# Error uploading big extensions to joomla on a localhost

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I get the following error when I tried uploading the Akeeba Backup extension on my localhost: "There was an error uploading this file to the server."

I tried uploading JCE Editor and it worked fine. I understand this error appears because I cannot upload extensions bigger than X MB (JCE is 1,5MB and Akeeba is 2,25MB). So my guess is I cannot upload extensions bigger than 2MB.

Researching I came across two solutions, neither worked for me.

First solution: 
In the file ini.php find the following line `upload_max_filesize = xM` and replace "x" with a value of 10 (for example). I could not find the above mentioned line in the ini.php file.

Second solution:
In your .htaccess add the following:

```
php_value max_upload_size 10M
```

added the code, nothing happened.

I am using Joomla 3.2

Comment: http://www.joomlabamboo.com/blog/how-to-joomla/how-to-use-the-discover-tool-in-joomla-3 try this as an alternate approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to manually find the correct line to edit, in your code editor, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> which will open up the "find" box. Copy and paste **upload_max_filesize** and click "find". This will take you to the exact line where it is located. Once changed, save the file and restart Apache/All services on your localhost.

Comment: I did exactly as you said, however, my editor could not find anything. Maybe I am searching within the wrong file, I just searched for "ini.php" in the folder where all my joomla files are. Only one file came up, this was its directory: C:/wamp/www/demo/libraries/joomla/registry/format/ini.php

Comment: No, thats the wrong file. The php.ini os not inside your Joomla folder, it will be within the xampp or wamp folder. Which program are you using for your local host?

Comment: Left click the green wamp server icon on your windows taskbar, then go to "php setting", then click "php.ini". This will open the correct file ;)