# Application Instantiation Error displaying when trying to install joomla on a localhost

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I created a mySQL database called "testsite" using phpMyAdmin and downloaded all of my joomla files from my live site to the folder wamp/www/testsite. (I already have a live site that I would like to have on a localhost).

When I want to look at the site I get the following error: "Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error"

I undestand this is because the configuration.php file is not set up properly, here is the relevant part of it, I don't know where my mistake is...

```
    public $dbtype = 'mysql';
    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = '';
    public $db = 'testsite';
    public $dbprefix = '';
```

I know this does or should not cause the error, but here is the other part that I need to change and am not sure as to what exactly to change, this is what I have tried:

```
    public $log_path = '/C:/wamp/www/testsite/logs';
    public $tmp_path = '/C:/wamp/www/testsite/tmp';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, the database credentials you have entered in the configuration.php file aren't correct.

This line must be correct as you already mentioned you have created a database called **testsite**

```
public $db = 'testsite';
```

After this, you're supposed to create a user and assign this user to the database. You are currently using the user **root** which I believe is a default user, however have you assigned it to the database you created? Either way, I would not do this, I would create a completely new user with a password of your choice and assign this one to the database.

**Update**

You have strict errors appearing on your site. This happens a lot with Joomla and PHP 5.4+

Turn turn them off, firstly, open the **php.ini** file for wampserver ([check the last comment on my answer to another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411896/error-uploading-big-extensions-to-joomla-on-a-localhost/21412000#21412000))

Then set error reporting to :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

**Update 2**

Here is another approach that worked for me:

In the configuration.php look for `public $error_reporting = 'default';` and change it to `public $error_reporting = '30711';`

Comment: The **root** used is a default user, yes. 
I created a new user with a password and updated this in the configuration.php, still not working. I assume it is because I did not assign it to the database, how do I do this?

Comment: in PhpMyAdmin, go to the "**Users**" tab, then click "**Edit Privileges**" for the user of your choice. Then under the head "**Database-specific privileges**", you can add the database there ;)

Comment: Tried that, I now have my user assigned to my database **testsite**. I restarted WAMP but I still get the same error. what about the `$dbprefix`do I need to add anything there?

Comment: Right, that bit is done then. If you look at all the tables for your database, you will see they all start with a prefix, like so `jos_users`. So in this case, you would use `public $dbprefix = 'jos_'`. Make sure you also type in the password for the user you created in `public $password = '';`

Comment: password is set. I don't seem to have any tables in my **testsite** database, all I did was download all the joomla files I had on my server via FTP into the following folder: wamp/www/testsite
This is what I understood I had to do to get my site from a remotehost to a localhost.

Comment: That's the problem then. The Joomla site on your localhost is hooked up to a database without any tables. On your live host, export the database and import it via PhpMyAdmin on your localhost. Then go back and fill in the `$dbprefix` as you mentioned before

Comment: Ok, did just that, according to PHPMyAdmin it exported and imported correctly. However, when I check the front end I see a lot of orange error messages as well as my website. Here is on of the errors: Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\wamp\www\testsite\plugins\system\jumirouter\jumirouter.php on line 20
I can't log in as an administrator either, the same error as above appears, as well as "0 - An error has occurred."
Any ideas?

Comment: What version of PHP were you running on your live host? **And** what version of PHP are you running on your localhost?

Comment: My live host is running php 5.4.24 and my localhost is running php 5.4.12

Comment: The suggested edit was already in the php.ini file. This is what it said: Default Value: `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

Comment: @Michael - made a slight mistake before, see the updated code to add to the *php.ini*

Comment: I'm afraid errors still persist. Should I not have a look at the jumirouter.php file? As far as I know that is where the error is right?

Comment: I wouldn't start editing any core files for extensions. Personally, I would uninstall Jumi and use something else. Either that or contact the developer of Jumi to report the error

Comment: So the best solution would be to unistall Jumi and export and import my database again? Do you have any suggestion for an extension like Jumi?
That would get rid of most errors, though I guess the following one would persist as it's from my template: _Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\wamp\www\testsite\templates\my-template\html\com_content\article\default.php on line 43_
I believe it comes from an override I made once.

Comment: Strict standards are ok to have and aren't really anything to majorly worry about. If you have a look around Google, you will find methods to turn them off (having shown 1 method myself). In the Joomla backend in the Global Configuration, also ensure you have error reporting set to "System Default"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46356/discussion-between-michael-and-lodder)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but it may have been my fault. I had amended the my.cnf file in the mysql directory.

Set it back to the original settings and all worked ok.

Just for reference the file I edited was:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf